# Trying to inherit from unittest.TestCase and another class

Tags: python, unit-testing, multiple-inheritance, python-unittest

I have a base class (which inherits *only* from `object`) with common tests for a set of sorting algorithms. Now, for each specific algorithm, I would like to create a test class which inherits both from `unittest.TestCase` and this class with common tests for all sorting algorithms.

For example, I would like to create a class to test, say, a bubble sort. Currently, I'm doing:

```
import unittest

from ands.algorithms.sorting import bubble_sort
from tests.algorithms.sorting.base_tests import *


class TestBubbleSort(unittest.TestCase, SortingAlgoTests):

    def __init__(self):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self)
        SortingAlgoTests.__init__(self, bubble_sort, True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Now, when I run `TestBubbleSort` using the command:

```
coverage run -m unittest discover . -v
```

I get a bunch of errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 117, in parseArgs
    self._do_discovery(argv[2:])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 228, in _do_discovery
    self.test = loader.discover(self.start, self.pattern, self.top)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 341, in discover
    tests = list(self._find_tests(start_dir, pattern))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 398, in _find_tests
    full_path, pattern, namespace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 452, in _find_test_path
    return self.loadTestsFromModule(module, pattern=pattern), False
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 123, in loadTestsFromModule
    tests.append(self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 92, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.addTests(tests)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 57, in addTests
    for test in tests:
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Since I'm very new with this module `unittest`, but I had already created unit tests for a Java project, I'm not sure what's the problem.

I noticed that if I don't have the `__init__` method, i.e., `TestBubbleSort` looks like this:

```
import unittest

from ands.algorithms.sorting import bubble_sort
from tests.algorithms.sorting.base_tests import *


class TestBubbleSort(unittest.TestCase, SortingAlgoTests):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

I don't have the errors above anymore. The problem is that I need to pass the sorting algorithm to the `SortingAlgoTests` base class, so I need to call its constructor, and usually I would do it in the `__init__` method.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve the problem by modifying my `TestBubbleSort` to:

```
class TestBubbleSort(unittest.TestCase, SortingAlgoTests):

    def __init__(self, methodName="runTest"):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, methodName)
        SortingAlgoTests.__init__(self, bubble_sort, True)
```

Apparently, it is required that a subclass of `unittest.TestCase` has a `__init__` method with the signature similar to the one above, i.e., with a parameter `methodName`, which needs to be passed to the super constructor of `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have overridden addTest method in SortingAlgoTests class